# "A rumor circulated among the staff that he was being promoted to Vice President ." Is the part 'that...President' an adjective clause?

Tags: clauses, noun-phrases

If I re-frame the sentence as : "A rumor that he was being promoted to Vice President circulated among the staff", it seems that the part 'A rumor that he was ...President' is a phrase. 
The answer given is :

*The original sentence is a discontinuous noun phrase.*

My question is why isn't it an adjective clause in the original sentence? Isn't there proper verb form present in the portion I mentioned in the question?

Comment: Why would you think it was an adjective phrase? An adjective phrase would have an adjective as its head; which word is an adjective?

Comment: I said adjective clause not phrase. I don't know what an adjective phrase is.

Comment: The word 'clause' is generally used only for verb phrases. If you don't know what a phrase is you should [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase).

Comment: @curiousdannii Hmm, not really. *that he was a clown* is a clause. The verb phrase in that is *was a clown*.

Comment: @Araucaria Depends on your syntactic framework... in some X-bar based frameworks subjects occupy the specifier position which means they are internal to the phrase, so that the VP/IP (inflection phrase) *is* the whole of the clause. In this case though I was not quite speaking clearly enough, I just meant that 'clause' is used for verb based propositions (and sometimes verbless clauses), but it is not common to call an adjective phrase a clause

Comment: @curiousdannii Really? I though they were called relative clauses! (but I wouldn't use that term for a RC anyhow. There you go ... (shrugs)

Comment: @curiousdannii I get that with IP, but VP? That seems a bit odd to me ... It' more likely to be described as an IP right?

Comment: @Araucaria I really depends on the framework... I think in older analyses the inflections would be part of the VP directly rather than given phrases above it. In my simplified thinking a VP is still essentially equivalent to a sentence. But this is really getting rather off-topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Content clauses**

Many verbs take finite clauses as Complements, often introduced by the subordinator *that*:

- I know [that elephants like donuts]
- I said [that elephants like donuts]
- We allege [that elephants have been eating our donuts]

Many nouns can take finite clauses as Complements too:

- The idea [that elephants like donuts] is not new.
- The news [that elephants like donuts] is spreading like wildfire.
- The insinuation [that us elephants have been eating your donuts] is unwelcome.

Sometimes, especially if the clause is very long, it can break away from the noun and move to the end of the clause:

- The news is spreading like wildfire [that elephants like donuts].

These types of finite clauses that appear as the Complements of nouns and verbs are referred to as *content clauses* by sources such as the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*.

**Relative clauses**

Now, noun phrases which take content clauses look a bit like nouns being modified by relative clauses (a relative clause is a technical term for an adjective clause). Here are some nouns that genuinely are being modified by relative clauses:

- The news [that is spreading like wildfire] has astounded elephants everywhere.
- That idea [that I got from the internet] has proved very popular.
- The insinuation [that you made] was most unwelcome.
- The news [that he'd been waiting for] arrived.

Now sometimes, for example if we have an intransitive verb and a long relative clause, relative clauses can also break off and move to the end of the sentence:

- The news arrived that he'd been waiting for.

**Distinguishing content clauses and relative clauses**

Now there are different ways to try to understand whether a clause is a content clause or a relative clause (adjective clause). If the clause is a content clause, it will be grammatically complete in the sense that all the material after the word *that* will work as a stand alone sentence. So for example, in "the news that **England had won the world cup**", the material after *that* will work as a stand alone sentence:

- England had won the world cup.

We can contrast this with "the news that **he'd been waiting for**" from one of the relative clause examples:

- *He'd been waiting for. (ungrammatical)

Here there is a gap after the word *for* which we understand as representing *the news*. We can represent the sentence like this:

- The news that [he'd been waiting for <del>the news</del>]

However, it isn't  always so simple to see where the gap in a relative clause actually is. A better way to see what kind of clause is involved is to see if you can change the word *that*. The word *that* can nearly always be substituted by *which* or *who* when it occurs in a relative clause modifying a noun. However, the subordinator *that* which we find in content clauses cannot be substituted with a relative *wh-* word. Consider the following examples:

- The news **which** he'd been waiting for arrived. (grammatical - because relative clause)
- The news **which** elephants like donuts is spreading like wildfire. (ungrammatical - because content clause).

**The Original Poster's example**

> A rumor circulated among the staff  that he was being promoted to Vice President.

In this sentence the clause *that he was being promoted to Vice President* has broken away from the head of the noun phrase *a rumour*. As reconstruted by the Original Poster, the canonical phrase order would be:

- A rumor that he was being promoted to Vice President circulated among the staff

Here the main verb in the sentence (the matrix verb) is the word *circulated*. All the material before the verb constitutes one long noun phrase functioning as Subject of the sentence. The clause following *rumour* has its own verb. We can show that this is a content clause and not a relative clause by substituting the word *which* for the word *that*:

- *A rumor which he was being promoted to Vice President circulated among the staff. (ungrammatical)

---

**Notes for grammar junkies**

The phenomenon where the material after the noun in an NP breaks away and drifts to the end of the clause is known as *extraposition from noun phrase movement* or *extraposition from NP* for short. It usually only happens if the element is quite long.

Comment: @archangel89 Thanks :) You might want to wait a day or two before selecting an answer though ... You might get a much better one! People might not want to answer your question if you've already selected an answer. And your question's a good question. It deserves lots of answers!

Comment: @Araucaria Say I take an example: 'The reason which Ram gave is unclear'. To me it is adjective clause. But say the sentence is: 'The reason is clear to us why elephants are not eating donuts'. To me, after going through your explanation, it is noun clause. Am i right? Again in the first example if I replace 'The reason...gave' by 'it', it seems it is acting like a noun/pronoun. Although I know, it fits into relative clause category, do you think it is little confusing? Any explanations?

Comment: @archangel89 As far as clauses modifying nouns go, if it has a *wh-* word at the beginning it's definitely a relative clause. Of course the function of the whole large noun phrase can be the same as any other noun. So in *the reason is clear to us*, the NP *the reason* is the Subject . In *The reason why she left is unclear to us*, the whole phrase *the reason why she left* is the Subject. The same would be true if we had a noun with a content clause too. "The news that she wasn't coming was a great shock" has "The news that she wasn't coming" as a Subject. ...

Comment: @archangel89 ... So the function of the NP doesn't tell us whether the NP contains a content clause or a relative clause!

Comment: @archangel89 The word *reason* is a very odd animal. It's the only noun, so they say, that will take a relative clause with *why*.

Comment: The reason is clear to us why elephants are not eating donuts....This is an example of  content clause, right? You just said 'reason' is the odd man out in a sense it can form relative clause with 'why'. But does that mean the sentence above states a relative clause?

Comment: @archangel89 No it's a relative clause (in the current thinking). It's unusual because it uses *why* instead of *which* or *who*. It has broken away from the noun phrase and moved to the end of the sentence.